# Why do I get a FileNotFoundException for a URL call in Android on using Azure face API?

Tags: java, android, json, azure, azure-cognitive-services

This is what i tried on Android to compare if two faces belong to the same person. I have also presented my error code at the end. Does this have something to do with the API?

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify?faceId1=" + face1 + "&faceId2=" + face2);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "----");
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        getting = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.v("Gettinganswer", getting);
        return  getting;
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
    return null;
}
```

---

```
2018-10-24 23:45:44.200 25987-26725/com.example.android.staysaferesq E/ERROR: https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify?faceId1=03ab5c58-86bb-4eef-a89e-56d4ce76e95b&faceId2=03ab5c58-86bb-4eef-a89e-56d4ce76e95b
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://southeastasia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify?faceId1=03ab5c58-86bb-4eef-a89e-56d4ce76e95b&faceId2=03ab5c58-86bb-4eef-a89e-56d4ce76e95b
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.android.staysaferesq.FaceActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(FaceActivity.java:301)
        at com.example.android.staysaferesq.FaceActivity$RetrieveFeedTask.doInBackground(FaceActivity.java:275)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this have something to do with the API?

According to the document we could know the face verify API endpoint should be

```
post https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify
```

The **body** format is

```
{
 "faceId1": "xxxxxxxx",
 "faceId2": "xxxxx",
}
```